# Why is 18.04 still using nvidia 390 while current nvidia driver is 410

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, nvidia-geforce

Just curious as to why the current nvidia drivers are not the latest.

Not a complaint, and not interested particularly upgrading beyond Ubuntu's current drivers.

This is not a GENERAL QUESTION about packages, it is about a specific version of of Ubuntu and also about about specific proprietary drivers, nvidia.

Comment: It takes them time to test so many many different packages from multiple developers.